# Where should one go for Magento Support?

Tags: discussion

After migrating from `stackoverflow.com/tags/magento` and the old community forum at magento.com, it seems that we are now left with two separate and capable forums for Magento support:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/
and
http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/bd-p/devqa

My questions are:
Which forum should be in primary use?
Is there any advantage of one forum over the other?
Are certain types of questions better suited on either forum?
Is there a different visitor persona on either forum or are they similar?
How about engagement levels?

Also if anyone could compile a list of awesome Magento support resources delineated by user experience and role that could be super helpful.

---

Magento community forums are also very focused on technical issues. See list of forum categories:

[image: Magento Community Forum Cats]

Comment: It's more for these kinds of 'soft' questions, ones that are related to forum policy etc. On the main forum we focus on technical questions

Answer (score 1):

For a list of resources check out https://github.com/aleron75/mageres by Alessandro Ronchi.

This forums primary focus is technical questions. All others are better off on the community.magento.com forum

Comment: It seems that the community.magento.com forums share a very similar focus on technical issues. See added screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for that list.